# Serializer django rest framework. Как изменить структуру json?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-model

В моем проекте Django необходимо реализовать API с методом GET.

Вот часть моего кода:

models.py:

```
class Color(models.Model):
temp = models.IntegerField(max_value=None, min_value=1)
correct = models.BooleanField()
top = models.IntegerField(max_value=None, min_value=1)
bottom = models.IntegerField(max_value=None, min_value=1)

class Speed(models.Model):
    start = models.TimeField()
    end = models.TimeField()

class Dog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    number = models.IntegerField(max_value=None, min_value=1)
    speed = models.ForeignKey('Speed', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)

class DogRequest(models.Model):
    id_name = models.IntegerField(max_value=None, min_value=1)
    colors = models.ForeignKey('color', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    dogs = models.ForeignKey('dog', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    DataTime = models.DateTimeField()
```

serializers.py:

```
class ColorSerilizer(serializers.Serializer):
    temp = serializers.IntegerField(max_value=None, min_value=1)
    correct = serializers.BooleanField()
    top = serializers.IntegerField(max_value=None, min_value=1)
    bottom = serializers.IntegerField(max_value=None, min_value=1)

class SpeedSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    start = serializers.TimeField()
    end = serializers.TimeField()

class DogSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    number = serializers.IntegerField(max_value=None, min_value=1)
    speed = SpeedSerializer()

class DogRequestSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id_name = serializers.IntegerField(max_value=None, min_value=1)
    color = ColorSerilizer()
    dog = DogSerializer()
    DataTime = serializers.DateTimeField()
```

мой views.py:

```
 @csrf_exempt
def DogRequestApi(request, id=0):
    if 'GET' == request.method:
        DogRequests = DogRequest.objects.all()
         DogRequest_serializer = DogRequestSerializer(DogRequests)
        return JsonResponse(DogRequest_serializer.data, safe=False)
```

При проведении запроса GET через постман я получаю следующую структуру:

```
{
"id_name": 44,
"color": {
    "temp": 33,
    "correct": true,
    "top": 33,
    "bottom": 33,
},
"dog": {
    "name": "bobi",
    "number": 33,
    "speed": {
        "start": "10:07:21",
        "end": "10:07:22"
    }
},
"DataTime": "2022-02-11T10:07:29Z"
```

Необходимо исправить один нюанс, блоков "dog" может быть несколько.

Как сделать следующую структуру?

```
{
"id_name": 44,
"color": {
    "temp": 33,
    "correct": true,
    "top": 33,
    "bottom": 33,
},
"dog": [{
    "name": "bobi",
    "number": 33,
    "speed": {
        "start": "10:07:21",
        "end": "10:07:22"
    }
},
"DataTime": "2022-02-11T10:07:29Z"
}]...
```

Comment: добавьте many=True 

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/

Comment: @maestro, я пробовал, это вызывает ошибку:

TypeError: 'dog ' object is not iterable.